# Graph api get common friends context

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get muttual friends between two facebook users. In the graph api explorer i'm trying using "me?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)", but this only returns something like common friends with myself then,and, the other user? What is the correct way to get common friends between two users? Where should I write the other user id or what is the way to get common friends between two users and not only common friends with myself?. Thanks I'm a graph api noob.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user.context/mutual_friends In the docs says "A list of Facebook friends that the session user and the request user have in common.". Then I assume that the session user could be determinated sending the access token and the request user is the {user-id} In the url request but when a replace it for a friend fb id I get a bug. ("message": "Unsupported get request.)

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
/{user_id}?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)
```

where `{user_id}` can be any id of a friend (which is also using the app, use `/me/friends` to retrieve the ids), or you need to povide the `appsecret_proof`  parameter for non-friends.

The *requesting user* is determined by the User Access Token used with this request, so that you don't have to specify this user.

See

> **Permissions**
>
> - A valid user access token with user_friends permission is required to view the mutual friends of other friends using the app.
> - The user in the request and the session user must both have granted user_friends permission to the app.
> - Additionally, the response will only include any mutual friends who have granted user_friends to the app.
> - If you want to call this endpoint on behalf two app-users who are not friends, then you must provide the appsecret_proof parameter along with the user access token when making the request. This means you must call this endpoint from your server.